# How does Cyclops sleep?

Tags: marvel, x-men, cyclops

Usually when someone wakes up, they open their eyes. Not a good thing if you're Scott Summers.

**So does he wear something to prevent his optic rays bursting out of his eyeballs when he wakes up?**

I would assume his visor or glasses may be uncomfortable to sleep with.

Comment: Maybe he has a ruby-lined sleep mask.

Comment: I would bet money that he wears some sort of eye-wear. i feel like X-Men Origins: Wolverine might have had a scene of it, but I'm not rewatching it to find out...

Comment: very carefully...

Comment: He just has a bit of shut-eye

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It looks like he keeps his mask on. Since the mask requires him to either touch the mask or use the hand switch, he's probably safe.

[image: Astonishing X-Men #2 - Cyclops and Emma Frost sleeping]

Just to cover all bases, there was a time between *All-New X-Men #3* and *Uncanny X-Men v.3 #22* when Cyclops had lost control of his powers such that the visor would not contain them, only his eyelids. I don't know how he slept at that time.

Comment: This takes "protection" to a whole new level.

Comment: Fun fact: Everyone who sleeps with their glasses on looks that good

Comment: Nice, thanks for your answer :-)

Answer (score 7):

He does indeed have a Ruby-Quartz sleep mask.[image]

Keeps his blasts in check, but is more comfortable than his glasses or visor.